# Joining two tables with columns that contain similar, but not the same values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, the first one has 4 columns like:

`ID` `NAME` `COUNTRY` `FILTERID`

and the second one has 2 columns like:

`ID` `COUNTRY`

I want to use this query:

```
SELECT F.Name
FROM   First as F, Second AS S
WHERE  F.Filterid = S.S_Id 
  AND  F.Country = S.Country
```

`S.Country` contains `Japan,Usa`, but `F.Country` have only `Japan`.

Please suggest solution.

Comment: I've proposed a solution below (using `INSTR` function), but I would probably recommend a more fundamental redesign, as having `S.Country` contain "Japan,Usa" suggests a curious data model. If you described the business problem, we might be able to recommend more robust data models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JOINS if you are using sql
For e.g.
Select * from table_one as one
INNER JOIN(you must know the different joins purposes before using joining the tables for reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp))
table_two as two
ON one.some_value_of_column_in_table_one = two.some_value_of_column_in_table_two
Thanks.

Comment: In sql lite also JOINS are possible......
Check out this @Nilesh http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/joins/

Comment: I already use Join but the problem is that S.country=India,Indore & F.Country=India so how can I get that particular value.

Comment: then why don't you use a common column in both the tables as a config column which you can use to make a join possible.

Comment: @nilesh if you are having only country name in one table like India and in other table you are having India,Indore then you can join the table like this
SELECT * FROM table_one one
INNER JOIN
table_two two ON two.Country LIKE one.Country

Comment: this solution is working for when S.Country=India & F.Country=India But it fails when S.Country=India,Usa & F.country=India

Comment: You can revert the table call if you have one table with values such like India say table_one and Other table with values like India,USA say table_two
Then you can use ON table_one.Country LIKE table_two Country
Else if vice versa
You can try table_two.Country LIKE table_one.Country
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have to write `JOIN` query as you want to get items from two tables....

You can use like,

`SELECT F.Name FROM First F JOIN Second S ON F.Country=S.Country`

Comment: I already use join but the problem is that S.Country contain India,Indore & F. Country contain only India so this query isn't working for me.

Comment: The problem is that S.country=India,Indore & F.Country=India so how can I get that particular value.

Answer (score 0):

If one country field is a substring of another, use the `INSTR` [function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html):

```
SELECT F.Name FROM First AS F, Second AS S WHERE F.Filterid=S.id AND INSTR(S.Country, F.Country) > 0
```

This will return records if `F.Country` occurs within `S.Country` (and, obviously, also if the `F.Filterid=S.id`, as per your original SQL).

Or you can structure this as a JOIN, too:

```
SELECT F.Name FROM First AS F JOIN Second AS S ON F.Filterid=S.id AND INSTR(S.Country, F.Country) > 0
```

Comment: By the way, I notice that the other answers have dropped the `F.Filterid=S.id` clause. If you decided that that clause was not necessary, then the SQL would just be `SELECT F.Name FROM First AS F JOIN Second AS S ON INSTR(S.Country, F.Country) > 0`

Comment: @Nilesh Can you paste your SQL here? When I use the above SQL in your simplified example, it works fine.